# DevExpress GridControl doesn't show modified field value

Tags: wpf, datagrid, devexpress, inotifypropertychanged

I have a GridControl and its columns are bound to fields from an INPC object in the ViewModel.
Here is an example:

```
<dxg:GridColumn Width="Auto"
 AllowEditing="False"
 FieldName="FullName"
 Header="Full name"
 SortOrder="Ascending"
 VisibleIndex="0"/>
```

When I modified one of the fields of the object behind the actual row, the GridControl doesn't show its modified value ***until I scroll it out of view and show it again***.
Obviously the ViewModel can't reach the View, so it can't call any refresh methods.

What should I do to make it appear immediately?

Comment: I've tried to reproduce the issue you described with using the simple collection of INPC objects but my attempt was unsuccessful. All things operates correctly for me and all the DXGrid's updates immediately occurs after changing any of the NPC-properties, related to the specific item, when the collection(`List<T>` or `ObservableCollection<T>`) of these items is bound to DXGrid .
Please provide us with more details on your implementation of ViewModel and your ViewModels collection.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Model object didn't call PropertyChanged as expected. After changing that, it worked well.